# TimeDistributed layer and return sequences etc for LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, neural-network, keras, lstm, keras-layer

Sorry I am new to RNN. I have read  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42755820/how-to-use-return-sequences-option-and-timedistributed-layer-in-keras/%22this%20post%22) on TimeDistributed layer.

I have reshaped my data in to Keras requried  `[samples, time_steps, features]`: `[140*50*19]`, which means I have 140 data points, each has 50 time steps, and 19 features. My output is shaped `[140*50*1]`. I care more about the last data point's accuracy. This is a regression problem.

My current code is :

```
x = Input((None, X_train.shape[-1]) , name='input')
lstm_kwargs = { 'dropout_W': 0.25, 'return_sequences': True, 'consume_less': 'gpu'} 
lstm1 = LSTM(64, name='lstm1', **lstm_kwargs)(x)
output = Dense(1, activation='relu', name='output')(lstm1)
model = Model(input=x, output=output)
sgd = SGD(lr=0.00006, momentum=0.8, decay=0, nesterov=False)
optimizer = sgd
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mean_squared_error')
```

My questions are:

1. My case is many-to-many, so I need to use `return_sequences=True`? How about if I only need the last time step's prediction, it would be many-to-one. So I need to my output to be `[140*1*1]` and `return_sequences=False`?
2. Is there anyway to enhance my last time points accuracy if I use many-to-many? I care more about it than the other points accuracy.
3. I have tried to use TimeDistributed layer as

   ```
   output = TimeDistributed(Dense(1, activation='relu'), name='output')(lstm1)
   ```

   the performance seems to be worse than without using TimeDistributed layer. Why is this so?
4. I tried to use `optimizer=RMSprop(lr=0.001)`. I thought `RMSprop` is supposed to stabilize the NN. But I was never able to get good result using `RMSprop`.
5. How do I choose a good `lr` and momentum for `SGD`? I have been testing on different combinations manually. Is there a cross validation method in keras?

Comment: Why do you write `[140*50*19]` instead of `[140, 50, 19]`? Is the shape actually `[133000]`?

Comment: Thank you, I did meant [140, 50, 19]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So:

1. Yes - `return_sequences=False` makes your network to output only a last element of sequence prediction.
2. You could define the output slicing using the [Lambda](https://keras.io/layers/core/#lambda) layer. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43037258/slice-split-a-layer-in-keras-as-in-caffe) you could find an example on how to do this. Having the output sliced you can provide the additional output where you'll feed the values of the last timestep.
3. From the computational point of view these two approaches are equivalent. Maybe the problem lies in randomness introduced by weight sampling.
4. Actually - using `RMSProp` as a first choice for RNNs is a rule of thumb - not a general proved law. Moreover - it is strongly adviced not to change it's parameters. So this might cause the problems. Another thing is that `LSTM` needs a lot of time to stabalize. Maybe you need to leave it for more epochs. Last thing - is that maybe your data could favour another activation function.
5. You could use a [`keras.sklearnWrapper`](https://keras.io/scikit-learn-api/).

Comment: Dear, If you set return_sequences = True, so the shape of output will be [140,50,1]. In this case, how many neurons can I consider at output? Just 1 neuron, 50 neurons, or 1 neuron foreach timestep totalizing 50?